# How to Use Template for Wpf DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, templates, wpfdatagrid, contentpresenter

I have a template for datagrid like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" x:Key="zoomableControl">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid  
            <ContentPresenter>
            </ContentPresenter>
            <Slider  Name="zoomSlider" Minimum="1" Maximum="100" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform  ScaleX="{Binding Path=Value,ElementName=zoomSlider}" ScaleY="{Binding Path=Value,ElementName=zoomSlider}"/>
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</ControlTemplate>
```

and use it like this:

```
 <DataGrid  Template="{StaticResource zoomableControl}"  ...>
```

I want to show datagrid in ScrollViewer inside the template, but it doesn't show anything. What's the problem?

Comment: Does hosting a DataGrid within a scrollviewer make sense? a DataGrid has a scrollable content section - so you will end up with a nested scrolling effect.

Comment: i just want to know how can i show datagrid in contentpresenter?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentPresenter >
        </ContentPresenter>
        <Slider  Name="zoomSlider" Minimum="1" Maximum="100" Visibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform  ScaleX="{Binding Path=Value,ElementName=zoomSlider}" ScaleY="{Binding Path=Value,ElementName=zoomSlider}"/>
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
    </Grid>
```

Your ContentPresenter and Slider are in same row of Grid so the ContentPresenter is not displayed as Slider overrides over it.I hope this will help.

Comment: slider is hidden,and i want to be sure that can datagrid placed in contentpresenter or i need to write some more code?

Comment: Yes it will and set the Visisbility of Slider equal to Collapsed , because when you set Visibility Hidden ,The space is covered by control however the control is not visible